# Embedding HTML in Flash using Deng

Tags: flash, xhtml, adobe, plugins

The [Deng](http://deng.com.br) XML browser engine claims to be able to render XHTML within Flash objects.  Does anyone have any experience using it in this capacity or could recommend alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Last time I checked, all unofficial flash based render engines were far from complete. You may find some Java applet library or wrapper for gecko engine (that's the one firefox uses). JavaFX also promisses to release a Webkit component (engine used by Safari and Chrome) named JWebPane in a future release.
If you're building a desktop application with Adobe AIR, then you have a native solution, with `HTMLLoader` class.